# Divshot Ember app not reading production environment variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-cli, divshot

I have an ember-cli application that I'm deploying to Divshot using the [ember-cli-divshot addon](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-divshot).  In my `config/environment.js` file I want to have a different `api` between development and production.

Inside `var ENV = {}` I have:

`api: 'http://localhost:3000'`

And the I have this for production:

```
if (environment === 'production')
  ENV.api = '<my production api>'
}
```

However when I do `divshot push production`, my Ember app is trying to hit the localhost endpoint for the api.

Answer (score 2):

After some work I realized that I need to make sure the I'm building and deploying the ***production*** version of my Ember app, which is actually built into the ember-cli-divshot addon by prepending the deploy command with `ember` like this:

`ember divshot push production`

Comment: Thanks for this. After maybe an hour or two trying to figure this out, I came across this answer. I wasn't aware that there's a difference between divshot push production and ember divshot push production. In fact, I didn't even have ember-cli-divshot installed. Now I see that you really need ember-cli-divshot installed and used as above in order to make good use of divshot with ember-cli.